# Creating NSNumber with a #define variable

Tags: ios, types, 64-bit, nsnumber, type-conversion

From my understanding of NSNumber, if you create NSNumber with a certain data type, you need to access the variable with that same data type. For example

```
NSNumber *myIntNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
int myInt = [myIntNumber intValue];

NSNumber *myNSIntegerNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1];
NSInteger myInteger = [myIntNumber integerValue];
```

If a NSNumber is created using a #define variable:

```
#define MY_DEFINE 6
```

does that mean that I cannot do the following

```
NSNumber *myNSIntegerNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:MY_DEFINE];
NSInteger myInteger = [myIntNumber integerValue];
```

because MY_DEFINE is not a NSInteger?

I know that the above code would work in a 32-bit app, but I am trying to make sure that it will work on a 64-bit app, which is much more picky about these things, as well. And of course, it never hurts to do things properly.

If I cannot do the above, should I try to define MY_DEFINE differently so that I could use it to create a NSNumber that can later be used to retrieve a NSInteger?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your understanding of `NSNumber` is incorrect. You can create an `NSNumber` with any type it supports and you can then use any of the supported type accessors. The two do not need to the same.

```
// Perfectly valid
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.14];
int val = [number intValue]; // results in 3
```

Your use of the `#define` is perfectly valid. The pre-compiler simply translates your code to:

```
NSNumber *myNSIntegerNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:6];
```

Remember, a `#define` is nothing more than simple copy and paste (at least in this type of simple form) done before the code is compiled.

You can even use modern syntax:

```
NSNumber *number = @MY_DEFINE;
```

which becomes:

```
NSNumber *number = @6;
```

BTW - why post this question? Why not just try it first?

Comment: I do not have a 64-bit device to try it on (working on getting one). My code does work fine in the simulator, but the 64-bit transition guide said it really should be tested on a 64-bit device, so I am trying to prepare my code the best I can. I have always approached NSInteger like you just explained it, but this section of the 64-bit transition guide gave me pause:

Comment: "Common Type-Conversion Problems in Cocoa Touch. Cocoa Touch, notably Core Foundation and Foundation, add additional situations to look for, because they offer ways to serialize a C data type or to capture it inside an Objective-C object.
NSInteger changes size in 64-bit code. The NSInteger type is used throughout Cocoa Touch; it is a 32-bit integer in the 32-bit runtime and a 64-bit integer in the 64-bit runtime. So when receiving information from a framework method that takes an NSInteger type, use the NSInteger type to hold the result.

Comment: Although you should never make the assumption that an NSInteger type is the same size as an int type, here are a few critical examples to look for:
Converting to or from an NSNumber object..."

Comment: Sorry for the long cut and paste. So it seems I am just interpreting the above statements incorrectly?